# Find a non-zero 2×2 matrix such that

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -2  \\
-8 & 4  \\
\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}
unknown & unknown  \\
 unknown & unknown  \\
\end{pmatrix}=    \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

What I tried doing is replacing all of the unknowns by a arbitrary variables, so $x,y,s,t$. that gave me $4$ variables (unknown), and $4$ equations.

i changed the upper left unknown to x, upper right to y, lower left to s, lower right to t. i ended up getting $4x-2s=0$, 
$4y-2t=0$, 
$-8x+4s=0$,
 $-8y+4t=0$
...

I tried isolating variables, but I ended up no where (kept getting 0=0).

Comment: i changed the upper left unknown to x, upper right to y, lower left to s, lower right to t. i ended up getting 4x-2s=0, 4y-2t=0, -8x+4s=0, -8y+4t=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\
c & d  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ denote the unknown matrix you want to find.

You get four equations,

$$-8a+4c=0$$
$$4a-2c=0$$
$$4b-2d=0$$
$$-8a+4d=0$$

First equation say that $-8a+4c=0$ in other words $8a=4c$ which further implies that $c=2a$. similarly you can use the third equation to conclude that $d=2b$

So you have these two relation $$c=2a$$ and $$d=2b$$
It means you are free to pick $a$ and then for $c$ you have to just double the value of $a$ you picked. Similarly for $b$ and $d$.

In particular,

Take $a=1$ then two times of $1$ is $2$ so $c=2$,

similarly $b=1,d=2$ and see whether they satisfy the equation or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer that I gave for the post that you deleted:

Let's consider

$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 &- 2 \\ - 8 & 4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x & y\\ s & t\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

We can focus on
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 &- 2 \\ - 8 & 4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ s \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Note that the two equations are dependent, hence

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 &- 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ s \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

That is we have $$2x-s=0$$

that is $s=2x$ is a solution.

Similarly, $t=2y$ is a solution, that is whenever, we decide $x$ and $y$, we can recover our $s$ and $t$.

There are non-trivial solutions to the system.

You just have to pick $x=y=1$, then you get $s=t=2$ to get a possible solution.